# Amplifing the output of a current transformer sensor

Tags: amplifier, sensor, current-transformer

I have to make a current transformer sensor from scratch for one of my projects this semester. I bought a torroid ferrite core and wrapped a copper wire around it. Plan was to thread a wire as the primary through the core and get the output.

When we did that the output voltage through the ends of the winding was very low (0.2 uV). How can I amplify this value at least up to about the mV range?

Comment: Why from scratch?  If it's an unavoidable requirement, look at the design of a suitable commercial unit. Copying it is not a matter of just wrapping a few turns around a toroid.|| If you are serious about getting quality answers then you need to be serious about providing quality information. What brand & model of toroid? Spec sheet? material? Core dimensions. Number of turns, ... | You may not know these things BUT if you want it to work by other than luck of trial and error you need to know as much as you  can about what you are using. | ...

Comment: You say 0.2 uA out - how is that measured. CT output is usually measured in Volts across a known resistor. Is your transformer resistively loaded. What do you know about current transformers. | You must help us help you.

Comment: "*... the output voltage through the ends of the winding was very low (0.2 microA).*" That's a measure of current, not voltage.

Comment: How did you measure 0.2uA? Or how did you calculate it?

Comment: My bad. It was uV, not uA. Sorry.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Our project was to make a current transformer sensor from scratch. We used a Toroid Ferrite Core of 16x8x5mm for Inductor Coil as the core and 0.5mm diameter copper wires for the windings. When we get the output it was wound 41 times.

Comment: @ulama measuring 1 µV at room temperature is extremely impressive. How did you do that?!

Comment: Ulama - if you refuse to provide all the information you have available you will almost certainly not get as much help as is possibe. You have now toild us the core size That is good BUT tgere is a vast amount that you know and have not told us. Adding one piece of information at a time frustrates people and they will stop helping. We don't know the input current, the core material (there are MANY ferrites) , the frequency , is it AC - won't work on DC, .... . ||

Comment: 41:1 is a very low ratio for a current transformer -- commercial units have hundreds or even thousands of turns on the secondary. How much current were you putting through the primary? But in any case, you should probably have gotten more output than that, and I'm wondering whether you wound your secondary with the correct geometry. Do your 41 turns pass through the center of the toroid, or are they just wrapped around the outside? Show us a picture of the completed unit.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon: "Volts across a known resistor" is exactly equivalent to current. Splitting hairs in this way does not help the OP. How do you think most multimeters measure current?

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I’m sorry but it is not that I don’t want to provide the details but I don’t know what the details are. This is my first time trying something like this and I’m trying to ask the question the best way I can. I’m really sorry

Comment: @Marcus Müller Using a digital multimeter at the lab.

Comment: @DaveTweed I know you know the following. I think you MAY have missed my point. That's not a jibe or criticism. Just an observation. AND if you haven't, then I have. If I've missed something in the following reason for my original statement then I'm happy to have it explained: This is a specialish case. A current transformer is intended to be used with a "burden resistor" to convert the output current to a voltage for measurement purposes. To express the output in mV (or uV) requires a burden resistor and for the reading to be useful it requires a specified R value.

Comment: @ulama 1. Are you measuring AC or DC current? 2. Do you know what the toroid material is (ie was it from a supplier or store or from used equipment or ...? 3. If you are measuring AC current, what is the frequency (mains 50 or 60 Hz or ...? 4. What else do you know?

Comment: @DaveTweed I wasn't trying to confuse or to be obtuse. As I hope you are aware, I try to be helpful to newcomers and to help them to succeed. As I know you know, newcomers quite often enter into a death by 1000 data driblets mode where they have quite a lot of information available but do not realise that they should and could provide all available information up front. They have changed uA to uV. They either know the toroid material or can explain why they don't. They know if it's AC OR DC (and may not realise that DC doesn't hunt), They MAY have some ideas about how CTs are used, or not. ...

Comment: @RussellMcMahon: Regardless of the method, the whole point of the measurement is to determine the *current* in the transformer secondary, and by inference, the corresponding current in the primary. Chastising the OP for giving you a current measurement is completely nonproductive. It's perfectly valid to connect a milliammeter directly to the output of a current transformer.

Comment: I still think there's a problem with the physical construction of the transformer, and I'd like to see a picture of it.

Comment: @DaveTweed I'm attempting to help the user. Odds are (based on many such past 'events') they are time bound and the project is due 'yesterday'
They know: -  what they have read and know about CTs. - frequency (0 or 50 or 60 or 400 or ?). - ~= primary current. - More ... | 'Castigation is not the aim. Attaining focus and rapid resolution is. There is a time for gentle slowness, and for urgent focusing. I **AIM** to get the balance right. I don't always manage. | There is some fundamental misunderstanding and poor practice here. Finding it asap is important and possibly project critical.

Comment: ninehertz's answer is good BUT you should tell us all that you know. : A current transformer is functionally the same as any other transformer - just used differently. The N turns (41 in this case) DECREASE the current IN the secondary by a factor of N and increase the secondary voltage by a factor of N. The ability to act as a transformer with a given "load" (here load = ammeter or "burden resistor") depends on primary current, frequency, core material, turns, ... . | IF THE PRIMARY CURRENT IS SMALL (1-100 mA) AND YOU ARE MEASURING OUTPUT **CURRENT** THEN FEWER TURNS WILL GIVE MORE CURRENT.

Answer (score 1):

Your toroidal sensor is basically a coil that converts the magnetic field lines generated by the current being sensed, into a voltage signal. Note that the current has to be AC in order for you to be able to measure it using an inductive sensor such as this.

Faraday's Law:
$$|V|=N\frac{d\phi}{dt}$$
$$|V|: \text{magnitude of induced voltage}$$
$$N: \text{number of turns in receiving coil}$$
$$\phi: \text{magnetic flux}$$

According to the Faraday's equation, you can increase the induced voltage several ways:

1. Increase the number of turns in toroidal coil by using smaller diameter wire or increasing the number of layers of windings.
2. Increase the change in flux by increasing the cross-sectional area of your toroidal coil by using a longer or thicker core material. As long as it makes a single wind of the coil use up more wire, that is increasing the cross-sectional area.
3. Increase the change in flux by increasing the strength of the B field induced by the current in the conductor. You can do this by using a core material with a higher magnetic permeability (mu) value.